# Не работает height через jQuery при Resize

Tags: jquery, frontend, resize

Есть функция, которая работает верно при `document.ready`, но не срабатывает при `resize()`. В чем может быть дело?

```
function PartialviewImg() {
    $(".ms-wk .ms-slide .ms-slide-bgcont .ms-partialview-img").each(
        function() {
            heightPartImg = $(this).height();
            widthPartImg = $(this).width();
            heightPartImg = Math.round((780 * heightPartImg) /
                widthPartImg);
            $(this).height(heightPartImg);
            $(this).parent().height(heightPartImg);
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().height(900);
            if ($(window).width() <= 780) {
                heightPartImg = $(this).height();
                widthPartImg = $(this).width();
                widthNewCont = $(window).width();
                if (widthPartImg > widthNewCont) {
                    widthPartImg = widthNewCont;
                }
                heightPartImg = Math.round((widthNewCont *
                    heightPartImg) / widthPartImg);
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().height(600);
            }
        });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    PartialviewImg();
});
```

В `document.ready` срабатывает на `load`.

Comment: Определите resize в document ready или попробуйте .on('resize', PartialviewImg)

Comment: Или попробуйте .on('resize',PartialviewImg )

Comment: _не срабатывает_ - это ничего не делает? показывает ошибку? делает что-то не правильно? уверены ли вы, что выполнение не заходит в функцию _PartialviewImg_?